# Should i ask agencies about the name of their client

Tags: resume, cover-letter

usually agencies doesnt include the name of their client( usually a company) should i ring them? or should i just put " your client's blah blah"?

Question is, Is it okay to just put the "your client" in a cover letter? like this

> I would fit right in with your client's collaborative culture.

or like this

> developer that is currently open at your client's company

or should i just ring the agency and ask the specific name of the company that is looking for new recruit? so that it would look like this

> developer that is currently open at AAA company.

or like this

> I would fit right in with AAA company's collaborative culture.

Even though i will submit my application to the agency and not on the actual employer?

I am talking about a recruitment agency. Cause i think this is where most company get a new recruit rather than having their own HR.

I was thinking it may be a privacy thing. But im not sure. Its just not good to just put "your clients" on my cover letter.

Comment: You're going to have to be a bit more specific. I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: Hello. Ive updated my post. is that okay now?

Comment: Much better! I think this will be received a bit better with the extra detail. Thanks!

Comment: If you are sending the agency a word-format cover letter, then there's a good chance they'll just edit it and put in the company's name for you.

Comment: So for now its okay to just put "your client's" in my cover letter?

Comment: Are you talking about working with an outsourced recruiter (i.e. headhunter)? As someone who has spent most of my career working for contractors who place their employees into their clients locations I found this question a bit confusing, even after your initial edits.  Some grammatical clean up might help also.

Comment: @GreenMatt Yes I am talking about outsourced recruiter like recruiment agencies. like hudson.com .

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, agencies want to talk to you *before* any CV gets sent to a company. My suggestion would be that you phone the agency now and say something like "Hey, I'm looking at your listing for [job x] and I'm very interested in pursuing this. Would it be possible to meet with you to discuss the role further? I can bring my CV or send it to you ahead of time if you give me an email address".

During this meeting they will give you more details about the job (usually including the company in question) as well as assessing if you are a good fit for it. At this point they usually suggest any improvements to your CV that are specific to this job, and you will be able to update the cover letter at this point too.

Answer (score 1):

I would ring the recruiter. Generally once you've had a "screening" as it were, if they think you're suitable they're very likely to send through the full job spec (even if one was online, I find recruiters normally do this, and this will then normally include the client name).
You can then adjust your cover letter and even tailor it to the company even more than just to a set of anonymous job requirements.

I tend to find once I've had this "screening" and explained to the recruiter what I'm looking for, they then go and sell you to the client anyway, making a cover letter almost superfluous in this situation (with the better recruiters anyway). It's also a good indicator of whether the recruiter is just looking for contacts, or actually has something - as they'll then go on to explain the potential leads they have for you.

Source: Very recently going through the recruitment process.

Comment: I havent had the screening yet. Is it still okay to ring them or leave it as it is and just put the "your client" on my letter?

Comment: It really is advantageous to you to ring them. You can probably get across your skills and requirements far better having a conversation than via email. This screening isn't particularly formal, it's basically the conversation you have with the recruiter about what you've been doing and why you want to move.
If you really don't wan't/can't ring them then send it though with "your client" or whatever you like, but make it clear that's what you've done. There would be nothing worse than them not checking it over and sending it as is (a mistake I've made once or twice!)